# Is it advisable to cover and uncover the clarinet mouthpiece to play each note?

Tags: technique, practice, clarinet

I took clarinet lessons only for 4 months and my teacher told me that I must cover and uncover the mouthpiece with the tongue between note and note. I find it difficult and I think I prefer to simply cut off the air flow and blow again, but I don't know if this is the right technique.

Comment: You must **absolutely** keep the air pressure up throughout the passage!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not really sure what you mean by cover and uncover. But as a clarinet player with nearly 30 years under my belt I would say there are three (four) ways of articulation.

1. Legato(Slur): You keep the air flow going, just change the fingering. This is shown by the arc over the notes.
2. Staccato: You stop the reed with your tongue and restart the tone by synchronized airflow and release of the reed by your tongue (the "Te-Te" tonguing). This is denoted as dots over or under the notes.
3. Portato/Tenuto: The more gentle stop, done with more a De-De tonguing. Shown by dots and arcs (Portato) or small bars (Tenuto).

The answer to "Should I always.." really depends on what's in the notes. I do not have my Baermann at hand, but I will check later and update. The clarinet school of Baermann is imho the Gold Standard for this questions.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you for pointing out those sloppy mistakes. I am by no means a native english speaker or writer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you *were* a native speaker. They were **tiny** mistakes. I've deleted that comment. Do delete yours if you'd like to.

Comment: Excellent answer! Do clarinettists also use Te-Ke and De-Ke in fast passages? I think flautists do.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian That's called double tonguing and is considered an advanced technique. But it does exist for clarinet and is used. 
I am German and therefore I was taught, clarinet wise, in a strong tradition that is quite different from the rest of the world. We have a different mechanic, different cut for reeds and therefore mouthpieces, different bore, different tonal ideal. We also don't do vibrato and don't double tonguing, but that's us.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian  Double-tonguing is possible but rarely sounds "clean."

Comment: @Oliver  clarinet vibrato is certainly acceptable in jazz/swing, of course!  It's slowly gaining acceptance for some 'classical' music.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I totally agree. And I like to do it to give a sustaining note a bit more substance. But as I said, it is neither wanted, nor taught in the german, classical, tradition. And the whole system is not tailored to that sound, either. The first time, I played a Boehm mouthpiece with a french cut reed, I was shocked, how much pitchbending is possible with that setup. That's the reason, why you normally won't the a jazz clarinetist playing a german Oehler mechanic, and if so, I would bet, he uses a special mouthpiece with french cut reeds.

Comment: What's the "*(four)*" about?  Is that where you stop the airflow using the back of your throat?  (Possibly the "Ke" that @OldBrixtonian was referring to?)

Comment: Additional air control    4. Using one's throat to make a "glottal uh-uh"    to control the airstream before it hits the mouthpiece and reed.

Comment: @Oliver You don't use double tongueing? How do you tongue fast passages?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian We have fast tongues.. I could could same saying about woodwind players, but I might collide with etiquette. 
To be honest, I guess most players will go for some kind of double tonguing, as they do for some kind of vibrato. I have a textbook teaching it. But that is university level stuff.

Comment: @Oliver Ha! Fast tongues would make you good salesmen! I didn't know about the Oehler system, but it explains the so-called 'veiled' tone of German woodwind sections. Weber certainly liked the sound, didn't he? Glancing at my score of the Oberon overture, I see that solo is a clarinet in A: *Maximum* veiling! Brightness is great, but I'm glad Bb trumpets have survived along with C ones. I've never heard a G trombone, though plenty of trombonists get misty-eyed when they remember the sound of them.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian The Oehler Mechanics is the "complete" german mechanic. It is easy recognizable by the one "closed" hole instead of a ring. You might call the german sound veiled. It would call it more centric, but it definitively has a more earthy, darker timbre. That is especially true for a clarinet in A. While a clarinet in C already sounds strange.. funny, how much different that is. How naive young me was, thinking, the different tuning is only for easy fingering.. I have to admit, It's fun talking to you. It's not often, you meet someone relishing such subtle differences.

Answer (score 6):

I guess your teacher was trying to get you to *tongue* each and every note. It's a better way than merely blowing to start each note - the result is more uniform and clearer, with a controlled start to the note, and more even playing.

Once you get into producing notes more clearly - especially their *attack*, you'll find that you can *slur* one note into another by simply changing fingers, but carry on with the blow. This makes moving from one note to the next smoother - somewhat reflecting the way we put words together in phrases and sentences.

Obviously, placing the tongue back on the reed *after* playing a note will stop it sounding, so again, teacher gave you more control over the end of each note too, which for a beginner makes it sound tidier.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, tonguing is a necessary technique.    There's hard tonguing, soft tonguing and many degrees in-between.  Starting a note with minimal or no tonguing is also a valid technique, but it would be a big mistake and very restrictive to try to make it the ONLY technique you use.

Try playing this without tonguing.   See what I mean?

(ENDING a note with the tongue is generally frowned upon. 'Taa...'  is a pleasing sound.  'Tu...t' isn't.)

[image]

Comment: Not always:  in any string of short or staccato notes, the tongue *should* be used to terminate each note.  For legato, the tongue simultaneously ends the old note and starts the new one.   The last note in a phrase, as you suggest, should not be cut off with the tongue

Answer (score 1):

Maybe lost in translation, but you shouldn't be using your tongue to cover/uncover as if to block the air flow. It's just a light touch of the tongue against the reed to stop the reed vibration. Like when you ring a bell, then touch your finger against it to silence the ringing. It may feel unusual at first, but try lighter or stronger pressure against the reed until it feel right to you. Good luck with your music study!

Comment: This is incorrect.  Proper tonguing does in fact stop the airflow entirely